# Segmentation Fault in dynamically array creation

Tags: c++

I was making a cpp program in which it takes two input from the user which determine the size of the 2d array and pass the values to the *mat* class constructor and dynamically create an array of the user's defined size. But, I don't know why it is not working and showing **segmentation fault**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class mat{
    int **a;
    int r, c;
    public:
        mat(int row, int col){
            r = row;
            c = col;
            
            for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
                *a = new int[r];
                *a++;
            }
            
        }
        void input(){
            for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
                for(int j = 0; i < c; j++){
                    cin >> a[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        void display(){
            for(int i = 0; i < r; i++){
                for(int j = 0; i < c; j++){
                    cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    
};

int main()
{
    int r, c;
    cout << "enter row :";
    cin >> r;
    cout << "enter column :";
    cin >> c;
    mat m(r, c);
    m.input();
    cout << "array \n";
    m.display();
}
```

I can feel that the issue is with the for loop in the constructor or maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: You need to initialize `a`.

Comment: Since a, r and c are private, you can use a flat `vector<int> a` and calculate it's 1D size using `r * c`.  Then translate the 2D x,y into `x + y * c` when accessing the 1D vector from the 2D coordinates.

Comment: you just allocated memory just to hold array of pointers of size r, but you never allocated any memory to hold actual data pointed by those pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new

Comment: What do you think `a` is pointing to when you do `*a = new int[r];`? (And once you've fixed that, what do you think it points to when the loop has finished?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class contains several errors.

- The variable `a` is never initialized. When we try to address the memory pointed to by `a` we get a segmentation fault. We can initialize it like this `a = new int*[r]`
- We should not change where `a` point's to, so don't use `a++`. Otherwise `a[i][j]` will not refer to the i'th row and the j'th column. We would also want to release the memory at some point.
- The inner loop for the columns `for(int j = 0; i < c; j++)` once entered will never terminate and will eventually produce a segmentation fault. We need to change `i < c` to `j < c`.

If we fix these errors, it looks like this:

```cpp
class mat {
    int** a;
    int r, c;
public:
    mat(int row, int col) {
        r = row;
        c = col;

        a = new int*[r];
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            a[i] = new int[c];
        }
    }
    void input() {
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                cin >> a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: actually I fixed all these issues after posting the question with the help of geeksforgeeks, still thank you so much for your answer.